# Digit Grouping in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, grouping, digit

How do we input digit grouping in C#? My code works but only for one instance. I have to constantly click it to group every number in the calculator. How do we do group it so that if we click it, it groups every number (not only the number presented), and if we uncheck the checkbox, it doesn't?

This is the current code:

```
NumberFormatInfo nFI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;


double int_value = Convert.ToDouble(textboxt1.text);


textbox1.Text = int_Value.ToString("N", nFI);
```

Comment: I am thinking this is possibly homework? also you may want to show some code as this is not very clear.

Comment: you may be curious to know that C# has no built-in ability to group digits.

Comment: definitely homework, the namespace is "_3rdQuarterExam_ADLM"

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're calling the formatting in the wrong place.  You probably want to call that `textbox1.Text = int_Value.ToString("N", nFI);` when your value is changing in addition to when you click the checkbox (ie, whenever you click on your calculator buttons or on `textboxt1.TextChanged` or whatever), and only if your checkbox is checked (`if (checkbox1.Checked == true) textbox1.Text...`).  It should also probably be in a separate function, that's called in all the places it's needed.

**Edit for clarity**

The problem you're likely having is that you have multiple sources that are changing the display in `textbox1`.  The code you posted is most likely in some `checkbox_CheckChanged(sender, e)` event handler.

You likely also have code elsewhere (maybe calculator buttons or something) that will change the value in your textbox (something like...

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(textbox.Text);
value = value + 1;
textbox1.Text = value.ToString();
```

in a +1 button, for example?)

What you want to do is have a separate `displayValue(double value)` function that will format it correctly all the time, maybe something like...

```
private void SetDisplayValue(double value)
{
    NumberFormatInfo nFI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat
    if (checkBox.Checked == true)
        textbox1.Text = value.ToString("N", nFI);
    else
        textbox1.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

and every place that you would have set textbox1.Text in your code, regardless of whether it's in a button or a _CheckChanged or whatnot, instead call that private function.

Comment: @14YearOldCuriousBoy: Sounds like the problem you're having is that it's only re-formatting your display (with the commas) when you actively click the checkbox, and not when other sources change what your textbox displays, it takes away that formatting.  Is that correct?

Comment: @14YearOldCuriousBoy: How's that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is the code:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace _3rdQuarterExam_ADLM
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    double x;
    double y;
    string operation;
    double memory;
    string current;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button1.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button1.Text;
        }

    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button13.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button13.Text;
        }

    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button6.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button6.Text;
        }

    }

    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button16.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button16.Text;
        }

    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button9.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button9.Text;
        }

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button3.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button3.Text;
        } 
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button10.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button10.Text;
        } 


    }

    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button15.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button15.Text;
        }

    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button8.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button8.Text;
        }

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button4.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button4.Text;
        }


    }

    private void Plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            operation = Plus.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            operation = Plus.Text;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void MINUS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            operation = MINUS.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            operation = MINUS.Text;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void Times_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            operation = Times.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            operation = Times.Text;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void DIVIDE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            operation = DIVIDE.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            operation = DIVIDE.Text;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void button24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        y = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        if (operation == Plus.Text)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(x + y);
        }
        else if (operation == MINUS.Text)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(x - y);
        }
        else if (operation == Times.Text)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(x * y);
        }
        else if (operation == DIVIDE.Text)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(x / y);
        }
    }

    private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
    }

    private void button27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "0.";
    }

    private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "0.";
        operation = Convert.ToString(ConsoleCancelEventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(x));
    }

    private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(1 / x);
    }

    private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        y = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(x * (y / 100));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(-1 * x);
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0.")
        {
            textBox1.Text = button5.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += button5.Text;
        }
    }

    private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        current = textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Paste(current);
    }

    private void aboutUToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.Show();

    }

    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        memory = 0;
        textBox1.Text = "0.";
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(memory);
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        memory = 0;
        memory += Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        memory += Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void digitGroupingToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (digitGroupingToolStripMenuItem.Checked)
        {
            NumberFormatInfo nFI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
            double int_value = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = int_value.ToString("N", nFI);
        }
        else
        {

        }
     }



    }

}
```

Where should we place it?